# Why are generators slower than callbacks?

Tags: go

I am trying to figure out which pattern is the fastest in Go to iterate over a range of values. Each one has obvious advantages and drawbacks, but speed will be an important factor for my usecase

Unsurprisingly, channels are the slowest.

However I'm surprised so see that there is a huge difference between the callback and the generator pattern, and I'm trying to understand what is going on. It seems to me that the performance should be about the same, but it's not.

Both are calling an anonymous function the same number of times, but I wonder if there is something related to context switching.

What is going on on the lower level?

I get those results:

```
BenchmarkIteratorMethods/generator-8               31970             36196 ns/op
BenchmarkIteratorMethods/callback-8              1000000              1193 ns/op
BenchmarkIteratorMethods/channel-8                  7999            148906 ns/op
```

My benchmark code:

```golang
package test

import (
    "testing"
)

const iteratorTestIterations = 1000

func iteratorGeneratorFunctionForTests() func() (int, bool) {
    i := 0
    return func() (int, bool) {
        for i < iteratorTestIterations {
            defer (func() {
                i++
            })()
            return i, false
        }

        return 0, true
    }
}
func iteratorCallbackForTests(callback func(value int) bool) {
    for i := 0; i < iteratorTestIterations; i++ {
        shouldContinue := callback(i)
        if !shouldContinue {
            break
        }
    }
}
func iteratorChannelForTests() chan int {
    channel := make(chan int)
    go (func() {
        for i := 0; i < iteratorTestIterations; i++ {
            channel <- i
        }

        close(channel)
    })()

    return channel
}

func BenchmarkIteratorMethods(b *testing.B) {
    b.Run("generator", func(b *testing.B) {
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            iterator := iteratorGeneratorFunctionForTests()
            for {
                value, end := iterator()
                if end {
                    break
                }
                _ = value
            }
        }
    })
    b.Run("callback", func(b *testing.B) {
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            iteratorCallbackForTests(func(value int) bool {
                _ = value
                return true
            })
        }
    })
    b.Run("channel", func(b *testing.B) {
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            for value := range iteratorChannelForTests() {
                _ = value
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: "Unsurprisingly, channels are the slowest." You mean unbuffered channels are slowest. Buffered channels almost certainly behave differently.

Comment: @Flimzy Thanks for your comment. Indeed, buffered channels are more than twice as efficient as unbuffered channels (but still way slower than the other options).

Answer (score 2):

I found why. It was actually related to my code. The defer with a function was too slow.

I replaced the first function with this:

```golang
func iteratorGeneratorFunctionForTests() func() (int, bool) {
    i := 0
    return func() (int, bool) {
        for i < iteratorTestIterations {
            value := i
            i++
            return value, false
        }

        return 0, true
    }
}
```

Now I get more logical results:

```
BenchmarkIteratorMethods/generator-8              773698              1442 ns/op
BenchmarkIteratorMethods/callback-8               966046              1168 ns/op
BenchmarkIteratorMethods/channel-8                  7710            145243 ns/op
```

Comment: Yes, I was just writing an answer to that effect. When you use defer in a loop, the deferred function can't be inlined, and the defer itself has to be placed on the heap, which makes work for the garbage collector. You don't need it here, so best avoid it.

Comment: This code makes no sense. Why do you have a loop, when you return in the end of the loop? It will never do more then 1 iteration.

Comment: @super it works the same as an `if`, in this case :) Either the loop body is entered once or not at all.

Comment: @hobbs It does techically work like an `if`, with the added downside that it confuses the reader and makes them question if any of the code in this question makes any sense.

Comment: @super You are right, it could also be written with an if. However this form conveys the iterative structure more clearly imho. I wrote it trying to get the same logic than a yield operator, but I understand that it's surprising. I think it makes sense semantically

Comment: @SebastienC. You can have your opinion, but I'm pretty sure that you are a minority that thinks using a loop instead of an if is somehow more clear. Not sure what you mean by iterative structure, but with this code snippet isolated it's just confusing.